# ExpressJS - Socket.IO with Route Separation

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, express

I'm trying to get my head around ExpressJS and Socket.IO. I've got my routes in a separate file which I include from my app.js:

```
var express = require('express')    
  , db = require('./db')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , models = require('./models/device')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , routes = require('./routes/myRoutes');
```

However when I try and emit an event from one of my routes I have no reference to socket.io.

```
exports.update = function(req, res){
    return Item.findById(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
       // Do some checks and save.
       socket.emit('updated');
    }
}
```

I understand why this might not be available. Rather I don't understand what the best way to get a handle on socket.io is from another file other than app.js. I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709912/separating-file-server-and-socket-io-logic-in-node-js) (see Ricardo's answer) but I'm still not clear. Ideally I would like to avoid doing this:

routes = requires("routes/myRoutes")(io);

Comment: you can avoid using the http module, although socket.io need a http server you can call it from the express dependency (3.x.x) thus: var app = express(), server = app.listen(3000), io = socket.listen(server);

Comment: Update: Take a look at feathers.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [express.io](http://express-io.org)

It has routing for realtime requests, and a bunch of other useful features.

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

app.io.route('example', function(req) {
    // do something interesting
}))

app.listen(7076)
```

As far as getting around having to pass the `io` object around.  You have a few options, which may or may not be "best" depending on who you ask.

- Make `io` or `app` global. (some people freak out over globals)
- Use `module.exports` and `require` the object in the other file. (can lead to circular dependency issues if not done properly)

Passing the `io` object is probably the cleanest simplest way, but you do have options.

Comment: Dead link.  Depreceated?

Comment: express.io link dead, It's redirecting to express-io.org

Answer (score 9):

Well you don't really need express.io for that. The easiest solution would be to export a new module and pass it a reference to socket.io instance.
So in your app.js you have :

```
var express = require('express'),
  ...
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , routes = require('./routes/myRoutes');
```

Now require a new module and pass it the socketio reference. Add this new line (in app.js) to do so :

```
require('./app/path/to/your/socketio/controller/socketio')(io);
```

Then create a new file in your `path/to/your/socketio/controller` called socketio.js

And finally in the socketio.js file, export your new module :

```
module.exports = function(io) {

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('captain', function(data) {

            console.log(data);

            socket.emit('america');
        });
    });
};
```

And there you go!

Comment: Thanks for the example. Could you elaborate further on not needing express? I've been thinking for a while about ways to implement a pure socket-based solution.

Comment: This "sockets.js" module strategy looks pretty popular on Github, but for the life of me - I cannot understand how the routes file (e.g ./routes/myRoutes) will have access to that module(sockets.js) later. :(

Answer (score 2):

socket.io doesn't work with routes, it works with sockets.

You add this code to app.js or a separate file which you include in app.js:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('update', function (your_id) {
    Item.findById(your_id, function(err, item) {
      socket.emit('send_update', item);
    }
  });
});
```

Your update route only renders a html document with javascript, containing:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.emit('update', { your_id: '1' });
  socket.on('send_update', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

So once the page is rendered and complete, the client-javascript will open a socket to the server and receive additional data.

See [more examples here.](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

*Disclaimer: Code written from scratch and not tested.*

Comment: Understood. My express app only acts as a restful API so there's not much going on view wise other than the default. I wanted to emit an event once a record had changed - just wasn't sure if I should send the notification from the server (once it's saved) or the client.

Comment: You could do that with a .post-route in express and an [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/change/)/[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) solution. Might be better than socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use closure. Ex:

```
exports.update = function(socket){
  return function(req, res) {
    //In here now you can have the reference to the socket io
    Item.findById(req.params.id, function(err, item) {
       // Do some checks and save.
       socket.emit('updated');
    }
  }
}
```

And:

```
app.post('/your_path', update(io));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the middleware router of [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) (I'm using 4.x).

In the external route file I put the "next" object:

```
module.exports = function(app, settings){
    app.post('/something', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    next();
    }
};
```

And in the main file I write the last route hop inside the io.on('connection'):

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // Final route for middlewares who need to interact with socket.io
    app.post('/something', function (req, res, next) {
        socket.emit('event', { result: 'ok' });
    });

});
```